# Fourier transform of $\text{sech}^4(x)$.

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to find the Fourier transform $F(k)$ of the function $f(x) = \text{sech}^4(x)$. I put it into wolfram alpha ([result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(fourier%20transform%20of%20sech%5E4(x)))), and we get that the transform is:

$$F(k) = \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}k(k^2+4) \text{csch}(\pi k/2)$$

Note that when $k = 0$ we get a problem. However in wolframs graph, there is not a problem, that is there is a value for $k=0$ (note that in wolfram they use $\omega$ instead of $k$):

[image]

How do we know what the value should be at $k = 0$?

Note the limit as $k\rightarrow 0$ in the expression for $F(k)$ is given as $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

Comment: Note that you have a factor proportional to $k$ in the result, so you can look at the limiting behavior as $k\to 0$ using your favorite method of evaluating limits.  The most straightforward is to probably plug in the first three terms for the Taylor series of $e^y$ and $e^{-y}$ in the definition of $\mathrm{csch}(y)$ and then evaluate.

Comment: So we have just plugged in the value of the limit at $k = 0$?

Comment: Something like that (or at least, Wolfram has). Since your function has a well-defined limit as $k\to 0$, Wolfram is presumably happy to define its value there as being that limit for purposes of plotting.

Comment: But if we write $F(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \text{sech}^4(x) e^{ikx} dx$ and evaluate at $k = 0$, we get just the integral across the reals line of $\text{sech}^4$ which should be $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{4}$, no? This is much smaller than what wolfram is putting there.

Comment: I mean $\frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi}$

Comment: There are different definitions of the Fourier transform; the one WA is using is [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(fourier+transform)&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,+%22%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22MathWorld%22%7D). The key point is that the factor of $2\pi$ is in the exponent, not overall. Hence $4/3$ is correct for the definition.

Comment: is it possible to recover the formula using my definition?

Comment: Alpha normalizes the Fourier transform with $1/\sqrt{2\pi},$ not $1/(2\pi),$ giving $4/3/\sqrt{2\pi}\approx 0.532$ for the height of the curve at $k=0.$